# How do I implement In App Purchases when using Cocos2d and Box2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, in-app-purchase

While the recommended tutorials online (Ray Wenderlich, Troy Brant and Mugunth Kumar) provide some information, most are out of date (methods have since been deprecated), some provide generic Xcode guidance (e.g. using Interface Builder, Root View Controllers, etc.) and others provide way too many add-on features that only confuse the person trying to implement in-app-purchases (or are trying to sell you their kit)...

In my case I'm simply trying to use in-app-purchases to "unlock" levels in a game I created using Cocos2d and Box2d.  I just need to display 2 items (More Levels, Skip Level) with the "Pay to Unlock Now" (Hence, I don't need a UITableView to display them or a long plist of in-apps).  Once a  "purchase" has been made the app needs to "know" so I can easily unlock the levels...

The various tutorials above were good for letting me know that I had to:

1. First create the app in apple.com/developers
2. Then add it to iTunes
3. Then create my in-app purchase items

The above was all very confusing (mostly) because of the iTunes involvement - seems like a lot of unnecessary duplication of accounts/logins/input/etc.  Now I am convinced that iTunes is a vestigial company idea that has yet to bite the dust.  But okay, if you want in-app-purchases you have to work with iTunes...

My problem is trying to adopt what has been stated in the tutorial code(s) (you know...retrieveProducts, buyProducts, etc.) for the Cocos2d/Box2d environment which does not use a "View Controller" and simply uses an App Delegate at it's top level...

I'm looking for a good, solid answer with detailed steps and sample code (if necessary), not a quick fix like "You need to blah blah check your plist settings and make sure it matches iTunes (obviously), blah blah read this (already have), blah blah and you're done".  I've already been there and that hasn't worked which is why I'm asking the question again here:

How do I implement In App Purchases when using Cocos2d and Box2d?

Assume that I have already done the necessary developer/iTunes configuration, have StoreKit and SystemConfiguration added to the project, have my distribution certificate in place, etc.

Start off by saying:

1. In your project, create a new Cocos2d/Box2d file called MyStoreKit.mm

Comment: "or the Cocos2d/Box2d environment which does not use a "View Controller" and simply uses an App Delegate at it's top level"... phew, really? check any sample project or your own. first of all in applicationDidFinishLaunch is created main viewController and it uses the openGL view.

Comment: Thanks. I now understand that a view controller is created in the App Delegate/applicationDidFinishLaunching...i.e., viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; viewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES; [viewController setView:glView]; [window addSubview: viewController.view]; But how can this be integrated with a store kit for in-apps?

Comment: I used MKStoreKit( https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit ) for in-apps. It is quite simple. For the list of your in-apps you can use both UIKit view(in this case you will create view using your mainViewController from appDelegate) or it will be just an additional node(scene), so you will continue work with openGLview of your game.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm trying out MKStoreKit 4.0.  It seems to be doing its thing (I get log messages) and connected it to my AppDelegate (Cocos2d) but fails to grab product info which suggests it's an iTunes setup problem, not an MKStoreKit problem...at least I'm getting closer.  There are so many factors to consider so it's challenging to troubleshoot...

Comment: I ended up using a combination of Troy Bryant, Ray Wenderlich and Lynda.com tutorials on how to do InApps.